# Building a 20x20 matrix with vibrator motor coins

Tags: fpga, programmable-logic, matrix, vibration-motor

I am currently doing a project that requires a 20x20 matrix with coin type vibrator motors.

[image]

I am not sure how to pull this off. What is the best way of driving all the motors all together? Provided that I will be applying different PWM frequencies to all of them at the same time.

I am going to be using a motor that requires **60 mA** at **3 V**:

[10x Nuevo DC 3 V 60mA 9000 +/-2000 RPM de la Moneda Del Teléfono Plana Motor de Vibración Que Vibra](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/10x-New-DC-3V-60mA-9000-2000RPM-Phone-Coin-Flat-Vibrating-Vibration-Motor/32713814130.html?spm=2114.30010308.3.44.MKYTsh&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10057_10056_10065_10068_10055_10054_10069_10059_10058_418_10073_10017_10071_10070_10060_10061_10052_10062_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_6&btsid=f799f86b-2b89-4158-b956-b80ca05fd1e4) (10x New 60mA DC 3V +/- 2000 RPM 9000 Coin Vibration Motor Phone Plana vibrating).

Comment: Well, we are not sure what it is you're trying to "pull off". Are you talking about a mechanical matrix, an electrical matrix, or something else? Does one motor at a time run, or do several -- and if so, in what patterns? In other words, we need a lot more context for your question.

Comment: I trying to pull of an electrical matrix. So just like in led matrix display but this time vibrator motors.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: What is the best way of diving all 20x20 motors? I am planning to apply PWM in all of them. maybe an fpga?

Comment: A passive(diode only) matrix arrangement is impractical for directly driving motors. You would only be able to power one "row" of motors at a time, limiting your maximum duty cycle to 5%. An active matrix (with one latch for every motor) is doable, but you would have to dedicate one [gated D latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Gated_D_latch) for every motor so there wouldn't be any benefit to just using a bunch of [shift registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register). A FPGA would be overkill as you won't need a particularly high PWM frequency, a μC is enough

Comment: What do you mean by μC? @jms

Comment: [Microcontroller](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller). While μC is a common acronym (along with MCU) in the field, I would have used the full term had the character limit not interfered.

Comment: oh right! I was thinking Micro coulombs. I got confused. getting back to the topic, using a microcontroller, wouldn't you need a special IC to to help manage the motors?

Comment: Would you edit your question and add the spec of the motors, or at least a link to motors? There may be different solutions depending on the current needs of the motors. When you say 'applying PWM to all of them', approximately how many different levels do you need? Also, do you care about the PWM frequency, ie. is it okay if its audible?

Comment: Yes, the shift registers I mentioned. A single high current open drain variant like the [TPIC6A596]("www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6a596.pdf") would be able to drive 8 motors simultaneously (with freewheeling diodes). To write data to them you would only need 3 pins (clock, data and output update), and you could daisy chain all 50 of them together. The data transfer is very efficient if one uses the SPI peripheral.

Comment: I greatly apologize for not making it clear. I will be controlling all motors in different PWM frequencies. So daisy chaining them won't work.

Comment: @gbulmer I am planning at least 16.

Comment: There is no reason why you couldn't daisy chain shift registers to do this, even if you want to control the PWM frequency of each motor independently. Suppose that the μC runs at 16 MHz. By connecting the start of the chain of shift registers to the SPI peripheral outputs, you could shift all 400 bits in 25 μs, so you could update the state of every motor 40000 times every second. There is nothing preventing you from selecting an individual PWM frequency and duty cycle for each motor, as long as it is divisible by the "frame rate" of 40 KHz. You will need a powerful microcontroller though.

Comment: LOL sorry I misinterpreted your message. I thought you meant daisy chaining the motors. Anyway, yeah I could see this working.

Comment: I'm just wondering *why* you need this large "phased array"  of 400 vibration motors, and why individual duty cycle control isn't enough with PWM frequency control being required as well. Whatever your end goal is, I've got a feeling that you could simplify the solution massively.

Comment: This is gonna be a sensory feedback system for the blind from a 2d depth sensor. The point is that I am trying to have the motors as precise and as accurate as possible. The alternatives that i have researched are really ineffective and inaccurate (electrodes or disassembled relays). I am going through an unexplored path. Although I have high hopes for it.

Comment: Do you need PWM or can they work okay just with a variable DC voltage? That might make for a simpler (if warmer) output stage design. How much accuracy do you need? Will say "4 bit" (16 different speeds) do, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

400 motors at 60mA per motor is a total of 24A maximum supply current. If you multiplex the motors then peak current will be much higher and could become impractical, so it will probably be best to drive them independently.

To apply different PWM frequencies to each motor, every one will need its own switching circuit (MOSFET, flyback diode, bulk capacitor). It's only a small step from there to providing each motor with its own MCU, all of which can be networked together and controlled from a single point.

Depending on the physical arrangement of the motors, it might be better to combine several motor drivers on a single pcb, *or* just make 400 individual boards and arrange them however you wish. Each board could have an input connector and a pass-through connector, so they can easily be daisy chained in rows or columns without extra wiring. This is similar to how 'intelligent' LED light strips work.

400 individual circuits might sound like an expensive way to do it, but with bulk purchasing it should work out to only a few dollars per board (less if you get them manufactured in China!).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need multiple PWM frequencies but wether independent pulse widths or just independent frequencies.

**Single PWM frecuency (Independent puse widths)**

I don't know if this motors will behave as LEDs. If the motor produces several forces depending on the width then this is what you might want.

You would need a single sawtooth oscilator, as much as 400 comparators (maybe many FPGAs), many analog references (FPGAs could be handy) and many analog multiplexers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB43MF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Independent frequencies**

If every motor works at independent frequencies, would you also need to modulate width? Maybe, if you want to have 3D feedback. If you want to modulate frequency only, then you need also a single frequency source (the maximmum frequency) you can obtain lower frequencies by means of a frequency divider. 4 bit programmable dividers will provide 16 different frequencies. The downside is that you need as much as 400 dividers (maybe a FPGAs could help here as well.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ7OX6.png)</sup>